# Jenkins job getting stuck after 20 to 30 minutes. Giving error as packet_write_wait: Broken pipe

Tags: jenkins, linux, jenkins-pipeline

There is a jenkins job that runs for more than an hour which deploys code on the target server. In this job it is getting stuck after 20 minutes and after 2 hours it is giving error as :

> packet_write_wait: Broken pipe.

On the target server the value of /etc/ssh/sshd_config file values are set to :
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 720
MaxSessions 50

Not getting the root cause of the issue or how should i troubleshoot it.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please note always keep practice to add Error, Details and objectives, What all you have tried etc to get quick and correct help for your query

Answer (score 0):

Helping hand :

- Broken pipe generally means there was a network disconnect for some reason
- The fix found so far is `mobile-shell`
- You will need to install [mosh-server](https://mosh.org/) in your target (the server you want to ssh'ed to) and `mosh-client` in your host machine.
- Another solution is to turn on `TCPKeepAlive` options under `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` in client ssh:

> TCPKeepAlive yes

- After applying above solution everything worked as expected and not observed broken pipe again :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks